# Agent not reading /etc/sysconfig/puppet server=

Tags: puppet

We have several servers working with puppet as agents today, but I'm having a problem with a new server running CentOS 7. Normally I would update the `/etc/sysconfig/puppet` file with the puppet master name and then start the daemon and move to signing the certificate on the master. However, puppet agent doesn't appear to be reading the `server = myhost.domain` in my config file. 
I get the following error in `/var/log/messages`:

> puppet-agent[11133]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

I tried:

```
myserver:root$ puppet agent --configprint server
puppet
myserver:root$
```

but the `/etc/sysconfig/puppet` file has:

```
PUPPET_SERVER=myserver.domain.com
```

Can you please help me understand why puppet agent doesn't get the server from the config file?

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/sysconfig/puppet` file is not typically read by the Puppet agent. (I'm not very familiar with CentOS operations, but I suppose that this location might hold some settings that are external to the process, such as environment, command line switches etc.)

You will want to use the proper `puppet` configuration file:

- `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` for Puppet `3.x` and earlier
- `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet.conf` for Puppet `4.x`

Answer (score 0):

so ran the following:

"puppet agent --no-daemonize --verbose --onetime --server puppetmaster.xxx.com"

this started puppet properly, requested certificate and I was able to sign on master. Then added:

server = puppetmaster.xxx.com

to /etc/puppet/puppet.conf and "systemctl restart puppet"

and it worked. Thanks for posts here and other places.